# Что произойдёт, если случится переполнение индексов в БД?

Tags: база-данных, индексы

Допустим, есть таблица TBL с полем ID типа INT, primary key, auto increment
Если будем постоянно добавлять и удалять строки, так что индекс достигнет значения INT_MAX, то что должно произойти? 
Экспериментальным путём я выяснил что индекс в моей БД переполнился и стал отрицательным, и я не смог удалить строку с отрицательным индексом. Я не уверен что это нормальное поведение. Так что хотелось бы выяснить как же должна вести себя БД при переполнении индекса. Вернуть ошибку или же сделать индекс отрицательным.

Comment: могу сказать, что я натыкался на переполнение индекса в mysql (32битного). После достижения максимально возвожно, больше записей в таблицу вставить нельзя было, хотя в базе не было записей.

Answer (score 1):

Для начала, это называется не "переполнением индекса", а "переполнением автоинкрементного поля".

Последствия зависят от конкретной СУБД, просто потому что автоинкрементные поля - фишка конкретных реализаций, их не существует в теории реляционных СУБД.

Большинство СУБД в этом случае сгенерируют ошибку при попытке вставки записи в таблицу, но какие-то могут попытаться сделать что-нибудь еще, вроде сброса счётчика в ноль, в отрицательные числа или попытаться найти "дырку" в существующих данных.

В общем случае точно известно только чего *не* произойдет - ни одна СУБД не вставит в таблицу запись с повторяющимся первичным ключом.

Кстати, отрицательное значение хотя и странное для автоинкрементного первичного ключа - но является вполне корректным значением для типа данных INT, поэтому не вполне понятно почему вы не смогли удалить его. Возможно, это была ошибка в вашем инструменте для доступа к БД, а не в самой БД. Попробуйте удалить такую запись SQL-запросом:

```
DELETE FROM tbl WHERE id = -2147483648
```

---

Избежать же этого эффекта проще простого - используйте BIGINT вместо INT. Такое поле "продержится" до переполнения в 4 миллиарда раз дольше - то есть наверняка дольше чем просуществует ваша программа.